# Package Version Creation Erroring on BusinessProcess

Tags: unlocked-package, 2gp

I have a business process on Case which references some Status values that I'd like to package. I have the CaseStatus values in an unpackaged standardValueSet that is being included via unpackagedMetadata. However, when I try to create a new package version, it errors saying
`Case.Default: Picklist value: Closed - Resolved not found`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BusinessProcess xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Default</fullName>
    <description>The default support process for Case record types</description>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <values>
        <fullName>Closed - Resolved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Closed - Unresolved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>New</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
    </values>
    <values>
        <fullName>Working</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </values>
</BusinessProcess>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>New</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
        <label>New</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Working</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Working</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>ClosedResolved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Closed - Resolved</label>
        <closed>true</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>ClosedUnresolved</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Closed - Unresolved</label>
        <closed>true</closed>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>On Hold</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>On Hold</label>
        <closed>false</closed>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

```
    {
      "path": "force-app/main",
      "package": "Package Name",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false,
      "unpackagedMetadata": {
        "path": "force-app/unpackaged"
      }
    }
```